# Como omitir campos con valor 0 en ejecucion de un trigger SQL TRIGGER

Tags: sql, sql-server, trigger

Tengo un Trigger que debe ejecutar una division para actualizar varios campos en una tabla luego de un update en otra, la cuestion es que algunas veces los campos tienen valor 0 lo que impide se ejecute la division, y necesito que se omitan esos campos si tienen ese valor pero que se ejecuten en los demas, ejemplo.

```
|TABLA_1|
|CAMPO_1|CAMPO_2|CAMPO_3|
| 50,00 | 30,01 | 0,00 |
| 0,10 | 45,00 | 22,09 |
```

Necesito que en la TABLA_1 se actualicen los campos, pero que omita CAMPO_3 ya que su valor es 0 y en el segundo caso que se omita el CAMPO_1 ya que su valor es cercano a 0 pero que igual lo haga en los otros 2.

Aqui esta el Trigger, gracias por su ayuda.

```
USE [AdminRGO]
GO
/****** Object:  Trigger [dbo].[AG_TR_CHANGE_FACTOR]    Script Date: 12/11/2021 14:57:52 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

-- =============================================
-- Create date: <Create 24/11/2020>
-- Description: <Actualización en las tablas
--               SAFACT | SAITEMFAC cuando  
--               cambia la Tasa>
-- =============================================
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[AG_TR_CHANGE_FACTOR]
   ON  [dbo].[SACONF] 
   FOR UPDATE
AS 

DECLARE 
    @pFactorOld DECIMAL(28,4),
    @pFactorNew DECIMAL(28,4),
    @pFactorReg DECIMAL(28,4),
    @pCodSucu   VARCHAR(5),
    @test       DECIMAL(28,4),
    --      
    @cTipoFac   VARCHAR(1),
    @cNumeroD   VARCHAR(20),
    @cFactor    DECIMAL(28,4),
    -- Cursor 1
    @cMonto     DECIMAL(28,4),
    @cMtoTax    DECIMAL(28,4),
    @cTGravable DECIMAL(28,4),  
    @cTExento   DECIMAL(28,4),
    @cMtoTotal  DECIMAL(28,4),
    @cContado   DECIMAL(28,4),
    @cCredito   DECIMAL(28,4),
    @cTotalPrd  DECIMAL(28,4),
    @cSaldoAct  DECIMAL(28,4),
    @cTotalSrv  DECIMAL(28,4),
    @cCancelC   DECIMAL(28,4),
    -- Cursor 2
    @cNroLinea  INT,
    @cNroLineaC INT,
    @cCodItem   VARCHAR(15),
    @cCantidad  DECIMAL(28,4),
    @cCosto     DECIMAL(28,4),
    @cTotalItem DECIMAL(28,4),
    @cPrecio    DECIMAL(28,4),
    @cPriceO    DECIMAL(28,4),
    @cdMtoTax   DECIMAL(28,4),
    @cdMtoTaxO  DECIMAL(28,4)
    --
--
--BEGIN
BEGIN TRY
    --
    SET NOCOUNT ON;  
    --
    SELECT  @pFactorOld=d.Factor,   --TASA ANTERIOR
            @pFactorNew=i.Factor,   --TASA ACTUALIZADA
            @pCodSucu=i.CodSucu
        FROM DELETED AS d
        JOIN INSERTED AS i
        ON d.CodSucu=i.CodSucu
        AND d.Descrip=i.Descrip;
    --
    DECLARE UPDMONTOSAFACT CURSOR LOCAL FOR
        Select  TipoFac,
                NumeroD,
                Factor,
                Monto,
                MtoTax,
                TGravable,
                TExento,
                MtoTotal,
                Contado,
                Credito,        
                TotalPrd,
                SaldoAct,
                TotalSrv,
                CancelC
        From SAFACT sf WITH (NOLOCK)
        Where CodSucu = @pCodSucu   
        And TipoFac in ('C','E','F','G')
        And FechaT >= Cast('01/11/2021' AS Date)
        
    
        Order by sf.TipoFac;            
    --
        IF UPDATE(FACTOR) 
            BEGIN
                --          
                OPEN UPDMONTOSAFACT
                FETCH NEXT FROM UPDMONTOSAFACT INTO
                    @cTipoFac,
                    @cNumeroD,
                    @cFactor,
                    @cMonto,
                    @cMtoTax,
                    @cTGravable,
                    @cTExento,
                    @cMtoTotal,
                    @cContado,
                    @cCredito,      
                    @cTotalPrd,
                    @cSaldoAct,
                    @cTotalSrv,
                    @cCancelC       
                WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 
                    BEGIN
                        -- 
                        IF FLOOR(@cFactor) <> 1
                            BEGIN
                                --
                                --SET @Test = 1/0;
                                SET @pFactorReg = @cFactor;
                                SET @cMonto = (@cMonto/@cFactor) * @pFactorNew;
                                SET @cMtoTax = (@cMtoTax/@cFactor) * @pFactorNew;
                                SET @cTGravable = (@cTGravable/@cFactor) * @pFactorNew;
                                SET @cTExento = (@cTExento/@cFactor) * @pFactorNew;
                                SET @cMtoTotal = (@cMtoTotal/@cFactor) * @pFactorNew;
                                SET @cContado = (@cContado/@cFactor) * @pFactorNew;
                                SET @cCredito = (@cCredito/@cFactor) * @pFactorNew;
                                SET @cTotalPrd = (@cTotalPrd/@cFactor) * @pFactorNew;
                                SET @cSaldoAct = (@cSaldoAct/@cFactor) * @pFactorNew;
                                SET @cTotalSrv = (@cTotalSrv/@cFactor) * @pFactorNew;
                                SET @cCancelC = (@cCancelC/@cFactor) * @pFactorNew;
                                --  
                                UPDATE SAFACT 
                                    SET Factor = @pFactorNew,
                                        Monto = @cMonto,
                                        MtoTax = @cMtoTax,
                                        TGravable = @cTGravable,
                                        TExento = @cTExento,
                                        MtoTotal = @cMtoTotal,
                                        Contado = @cContado,
                                        Credito = @cCredito,        
                                        TotalPrd = @cTotalPrd,
                                        SaldoAct = @cSaldoAct,
                                        TotalSrv = @cTotalSrv,
                                        CancelC = @cCancelC
                                    WHERE (codsucu=@pCodSucu) AND
                                        (numerod=@cNumeroD) AND
                                        (tipofac=@cTipoFac);
                                --      
                                DECLARE UPDMONTOSAITEMFAC CURSOR LOCAL FOR
                                    Select   sif.NroLinea
                                            ,sif.NroLineaC
                                            ,sif.CodItem
                                            ,sif.Cantidad
                                            ,sif.Costo
                                            ,sif.TotalItem
                                            ,sif.Precio
                                            ,sif.MtoTax
                                            ,sif.MtoTaxO
                                            ,sif.PriceO
                                    From SAITEMFAC sif WITH (NOLOCK)
                                    INNER JOIN SAFACT sf ON
                                        sf.CodSucu = sif.CodSucu
                                    AND sf.TipoFac = sif.TipoFac
                                    AND sf.NumeroD = sif.NumeroD
                                    Where sif.CodSucu = @pCodSucu
                                    AND sif.NumeroD = @cNumeroD
                                    AND sif.TipoFac = @cTipoFac;
                                OPEN UPDMONTOSAITEMFAC
                                FETCH NEXT FROM UPDMONTOSAITEMFAC INTO
                                    @cNroLinea,
                                    @cNroLineaC,
                                    @cCodItem,
                                    @cCantidad,
                                    @cCosto,
                                    @cTotalItem,
                                    @cPrecio,
                                    @cdMtoTax,
                                    @cdMtoTaxO,
                                    @cPriceO
                                WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 
                                    BEGIN
                                        -- 
                                        SET @cTotalItem = (@cTotalItem/@pFactorReg) * @pFactorNew;
                                        SET @cPrecio = (@cPrecio/@pFactorReg) * @pFactorNew;
                                        SET @cdMtoTax = (@cdMtoTax/@pFactorReg) * @pFactorNew;
                                        SET @cdMtoTaxO = (@cdMtoTaxO/@pFactorReg) * @pFactorNew;
                                        SET @cPriceO = (@cPriceO/@pFactorReg) * @pFactorNew;                                        
                                        --SET @cTotalItem = (@cCantidad*@cPrecio);
                                        --  
                                        UPDATE SAITEMFAC
                                            SET TotalItem = @cTotalItem,
                                                Precio = @cPrecio,
                                                MtoTax = @cdMtoTax,
                                                MtoTaxO = @cdMtoTaxO,
                                                PriceO = @cPriceO
                                        WHERE (codsucu=@pCodSucu) AND
                                            (numerod=@cNumeroD) AND
                                            (tipofac=@cTipoFac) AND 
                                            (NroLinea=@cNroLinea);                                          
                                        --  
                                        FETCH NEXT FROM UPDMONTOSAITEMFAC INTO
                                            @cNroLinea,
                                            @cNroLineaC,
                                            @cCodItem,
                                            @cCantidad,
                                            @cCosto,
                                            @cTotalItem,
                                            @cPrecio,
                                            @cdMtoTax,
                                            @cdMtoTaxO,
                                            @cPriceO    
                                    
                                    END
                                    --                          
                                CLOSE UPDMONTOSAITEMFAC
                                DEALLOCATE UPDMONTOSAITEMFAC
                                --                          
                            END                     
                        FETCH NEXT FROM UPDMONTOSAFACT INTO
                            @cTipoFac,
                            @cNumeroD,
                            @cFactor,
                            @cMonto,
                            @cMtoTax,
                            @cTGravable,
                            @cTExento,
                            @cMtoTotal,
                            @cContado,
                            @cCredito,      
                            @cTotalPrd,
                            @cSaldoAct,
                            @cTotalSrv,
                            @cCancelC                       
                    END
                    --
            
                CLOSE UPDMONTOSAFACT
                DEALLOCATE UPDMONTOSAFACT
            END 
    --
END TRY
--END
BEGIN CATCH
    DECLARE @ErrorMessage NVARCHAR(4000);  
    DECLARE @ErrorSeverity INT;  
    DECLARE @ErrorState INT;  
  
    SELECT   
        @ErrorMessage = ERROR_MESSAGE(),  
        @ErrorSeverity = ERROR_SEVERITY(),  
        @ErrorState = ERROR_STATE();  

    --Print 'Error en la ejecución del trigger. Detalles:  '+@ErrorMessage()
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION

    RAISERROR (@ErrorMessage,  
               @ErrorSeverity, 
               @ErrorState 
               );  
END CATCH
```

Comment: Tu problema va más allá de eso. Tener cursores anidados en un trigger es la receta perfecta para tener usuarios molestos por la lentitud del sistema.

Answer (score 2):

La solución para evitar el error es muy sencilla. Solo tienes que modificar el cero por 1 para que la división sea una operación neutra. Para esto podemos usar la combinación de funciones ISNULL/NULLIF.

Dejo un ejemplo de como evitar los errores, pero más aún, de como hacer los cambios a todas las filas al mismo tiempo en vez de hacerlo una por una. Sería importante resaltar que si el factor está afectando a las filas cada vez que se cambia, sería bueno aplicar la operación al momento de consultar y así evitas el uso de triggers cada vez que hay un cambio del mismo.

```
-- =============================================
-- Create date: <Create 24/11/2020>
-- Description: <Actualización en las tablas
--               SAFACT | SAITEMFAC cuando  
--               cambia la Tasa>
-- =============================================
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[AG_TR_CHANGE_FACTOR]
   ON  [dbo].[SACONF] 
   FOR UPDATE
AS 

BEGIN TRY

    SET NOCOUNT ON; 
    
    UPDATE sf 
        SET Factor      = i.Factor,
            Monto       = (Monto      / ISNULL( NULLIF( d.Factor, 0), 1)) * i.Factor,
            MtoTax      = (MtoTax     / ISNULL( NULLIF( d.Factor, 0), 1)) * i.Factor,
            TGravable   = (TGravable  / ISNULL( NULLIF( d.Factor, 0), 1)) * i.Factor,
            TExento     = (TExento    / ISNULL( NULLIF( d.Factor, 0), 1)) * i.Factor,
            MtoTotal    = (MtoTotal   / ISNULL( NULLIF( d.Factor, 0), 1)) * i.Factor,
            Contado     = (Contado    / ISNULL( NULLIF( d.Factor, 0), 1)) * i.Factor,
            Credito     = (Credito    / ISNULL( NULLIF( d.Factor, 0), 1)) * i.Factor,
            TotalPrd    = (TotalPrd   / ISNULL( NULLIF( d.Factor, 0), 1)) * i.Factor,
            SaldoAct    = (SaldoAct   / ISNULL( NULLIF( d.Factor, 0), 1)) * i.Factor,
            TotalSrv    = (TotalSrv   / ISNULL( NULLIF( d.Factor, 0), 1)) * i.Factor,
            CancelC     = (CancelC    / ISNULL( NULLIF( d.Factor, 0), 1)) * i.Factor
    From SAFACT   AS sf
    JOIN DELETED  AS d ON d.CodSucu = sf.CodSucu
    JOIN INSERTED AS i ON d.CodSucu = i.CodSucu
                        AND d.Descrip = i.Descrip
    Where sf.TipoFac in ('C','E','F','G')
    And   sf.FechaT >= Cast('01/11/2021' AS Date);
                             
    UPDATE sif
        SET TotalItem = (sif.TotalItem / ISNULL( NULLIF( d.Factor, 0), 1)) * i.Factor,
            Precio    = (sif.Precio    / ISNULL( NULLIF( d.Factor, 0), 1)) * i.Factor,
            MtoTax    = (sif.MtoTax    / ISNULL( NULLIF( d.Factor, 0), 1)) * i.Factor,
            MtoTaxO   = (sif.MtoTaxO   / ISNULL( NULLIF( d.Factor, 0), 1)) * i.Factor,
            PriceO    = (sif.PriceO    / ISNULL( NULLIF( d.Factor, 0), 1)) * i.Factor
    From SAITEMFAC AS sif
    JOIN SAFACT    AS sf ON sf.CodSucu = sif.CodSucu
                        AND sf.TipoFac = sif.TipoFac
                        AND sf.NumeroD = sif.NumeroD
    JOIN DELETED   AS d  ON d.CodSucu = sif.CodSucu
    JOIN INSERTED  AS i  ON d.CodSucu = i.CodSucu
                        AND d.Descrip = i.Descrip
    WHERE sf.TipoFac in ('C','E','F','G')
    AND   sf.FechaT >= Cast('01/11/2021' AS Date);                                          
                   
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    DECLARE @ErrorMessage NVARCHAR(4000);  
    DECLARE @ErrorSeverity INT;  
    DECLARE @ErrorState INT;  

    SELECT   
        @ErrorMessage = ERROR_MESSAGE(),  
        @ErrorSeverity = ERROR_SEVERITY(),  
        @ErrorState = ERROR_STATE();  

    --Print 'Error en la ejecución del trigger. Detalles:  '+@ErrorMessage()
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION

    RAISERROR (@ErrorMessage,  
               @ErrorSeverity, 
               @ErrorState 
               );  
END CATCH;
```

Comment: muchas gracias, el codigo me ayuda a solucionar muchos de los problemas (se que hay aun mas), uno de los que tengo es que si las columnas de precio, monto, etc. son 0 me da error porque seria ( 0 / 4.40) * 5.00).

Comment: Eso no debería dar error porque cero dividido por cualquier número es cero. Lo mismo con la multiplicación.

Answer (score 0):

Hola quisiera saber si te entendi estas buscando esto:

```
update TABLA_1 set
    CAMPO_1 = @CAMPO_1,
    CAMPO_2 = @CAMPO_2,
    CAMPO_3 = (case when @CAMPO_3>= 1 then @CAMPO_3 else CAMPO_3 end)
WHERE 
**CONDICION**
```

El Case te permite ver si el @CAMPO_3 es mayor que cero en ese caso lo actualiza sino lo deja del mismo valor que tenia.

Debo recalcar que lo que dijo Luis tiene mucha razon un trigger asi es la formula perfecta para tener usuarios molestos por lentitud del sistema.